# Colored horizontal lines in ODT template for Pandoc

Tags: xml, libreoffice, pandoc, odt

I'm trying to draw a coloured horizontal line at the beginning of an ODT file (OpenDocumentText for LibreOffice/OpenOffice) obtained by conversion from a `md` (Markdown text) file by using `pandoc`.

First I get the default template:

```
pandoc -D odt > template_odt.xml
```

I am able to draw a black horizontal line by typing `<text:p text:style-name="Horizontal_20_Line" />`, for example at this location in `template_odt.xml` :

```
...
$endif$
<text:p text:style-name="Horizontal_20_Line" />
$for(include-before)$
...
```

But how to attribute a color to this line? The style `Horizontal_20_line` is defined in the `styles.xml` file:

```
<style:style style:name="Horizontal_20_Line"
style:display-name="Horizontal Line" style:family="paragraph"
style:parent-style-name="Standard"
style:next-style-name="Text_20_body" style:class="html">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:margin-top="0in"
  fo:margin-bottom="0.1965in" style:contextual-spacing="false"
  style:border-line-width-bottom="0.0008in 0.0138in 0.0008in"
  fo:padding="0in" fo:border-left="none" fo:border-right="none"
  fo:border-top="none" fo:border-bottom="1.11pt double #808080"
  text:number-lines="false" text:line-number="0"
  style:join-border="false" />
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="6pt"
  style:font-size-asian="6pt" style:font-size-complex="6pt" />
</style:style>
```

So :

1. Can I add an attribute direclty in `template_odt.xml`, like :

   ```
   <text:p text:style-name="Horizontal_20_Line" line-color="red"?????/>
   ```
2. Or should I modify the style `Horizontal_20_line`, and how? I don't know where is the default `styles.xml` file and I don't know how to define a style in `template_odt.xml` (all my naive attempts have failed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to modify the `styles.xml` file. First get the `reference.odt` file in the pandoc folder or on [github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/reference.odt). Then, unzip this file. The color of the horizontal line is `#808080` in the default style:

```
<style:style style:name="Horizontal_20_Line"
style:display-name="Horizontal Line" style:family="paragraph"
style:parent-style-name="Standard"
style:next-style-name="Text_20_body" style:class="html">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:margin-top="0in"
  fo:margin-bottom="0.1965in" style:contextual-spacing="false"
  style:border-line-width-bottom="0.0008in 0.0138in 0.0008in"
  fo:padding="0in" fo:border-left="none" fo:border-right="none"
  fo:border-top="none" fo:border-bottom="1.11pt double #808080"
  text:number-lines="false" text:line-number="0"
  style:join-border="false" />
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="6pt"
  style:font-size-asian="6pt" style:font-size-complex="6pt" />
</style:style>
```

Modify the color and go to [How does Open Office compress its files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4957212/1100107) to zip back to `myreference.odt`. Then run pandoc as follows (assuming both `template_odt.xml` and `myreference.odt` are in the current directory):

```
pandoc -f markdown -t odt --template=template_odt.xml --reference-odt=myreference.odt myfile.md -o myfile.odt
```

Now I have a new problem : LibreOffice has to repair the output `odt` file, but this is another question...