# Powerpoint presentation unzip and zip as pptx not working

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-addins

I was trying to explore what's inside in pptx file. So, I searched online it says rename it as .zip and open it using the file explorer. It was working fine.

[image]

Then I zip all those things again and rename it as .pptx and it threw an error saying it was corrupted. Can anyone know why this happens and how to solve it? I just want my ppt back

These are all the screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Open Office compress its files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957212/how-does-open-office-compress-its-files)

Answer (score 3):

I would not extract the file, and then compress it to a .zip again. Use 7zip and edit the files that you want to without extracting it.
After editing you can save the modified zipped data to .pptx

ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/eb707730-db85-4884-8c27-000d51e081e6/pptx-file-renamed-to-quotzipquot-is-a-zip-folder-but?forum=officeitproprevious

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a Mac. That OS has two problems with unzipping to edit the XML:

1. The operating system creates an invisible **.DS_Store** file in every folder you view. These files are incompatible with the Office file when it is rezipped. You need to create a second disk drive that doesn't create those files.
2. The macOS Archive utility can't rezip the files correctly so an Office program can read them. You can work around this by using the command line Zip utility in Terminal.

Here's my how-to article covering both of those: [OOXML Hacking: Editing in macOS](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/11/xml-hacking-editing-in-os-x/)

But for most OOXML editing, you don't need to unzip and rezip. You can use a text editor like [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html) that can open Office files and edit them without unzipping. Or you can install the [OOXML Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn?hl=en) plugin in the Chrome browser and edit without unzipping.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue isn't limited to Mac. I have the same issue with a tool I built that unzips and rezips pptx files in PHP, and while searching for a solution, I've seen that simply unzipping/rezipping in windows already gives the error. However, opening the presentation in another tool than Powerpoint (e.g. using libreoffice) gives no error.

Comment: Try a different zip library. If you're using the built-in Windows zip utility, it is known to cause rezip errors because it creates an extra top level folder in the archive. For manual editing, I use WinZip and 7-zip in Windows and have no problems.

Comment: it's not a Windows utility, it is PHP code that unzips the pptx, alters the data, and then rezips, using ZipArchive, for a tool we developed.

Comment: Same difference. OOXML file compatibility is not guaranteed. If ZipArchive is not creating an OOXML-compatible archive, then you need to diagnose what it's doing wrong and configure it (or libzip, on which it depends) to deliver a correct result. Or use a different class: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3864-PHP-Create-and-extract-ZIP-archives-in-purely-in-PHP.html https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip https://www.findbestopensource.com/product/splitbrain-php-archive

Comment: I'm afraid your HowTo article link is dead

Comment: HowTo link fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is a bit old but here is how I worked around the issue doing the same thing, on Windows.

Just in case someone does the same mistake as me : doing a full extraction, modifying the content of the extracted folder, recompressing the folder with 7zip, renaming the zip into pptx (and deleting the original pptx in the process)... and failing to open it in Outlook.

So here is the WA :

Changed the pptx into a zip and then extracted the zip to change files in the extracted folder.

Created an empty pptx with powerpoint, renamed the pptx into a zip, opened the zip with the file explorer, copied the whole content of the first extracted folder into this "zip", renamed the zip in pptx and this worked.

Hope this will help :)